# The specified child already has a parent - TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm getting data from JSON to my object **BalanceSheet** and want to display the data in a Table layout but Im getting the following error,

The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
// on this line

```
 tableLayout.addView(data_row);
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/balance_table_SV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.BalanceTable">



</ScrollView>
```

and Activity :

```
public class BalanceTable extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView balance_table_SV;
    ArrayList<BalanceSheet> bsList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance_table);

        balance_table_SV = findViewById(R.id.balance_table_SV);

        bsList = (ArrayList<BalanceSheet>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();

        int rows = bsList.size();

        TableRow headers_row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow data_row = new TableRow(this);
        for(int i = -1; i < rows; i ++) {



            if (i == -1) {


                // need check
                headers_row.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
                TextView headers = new TextView(this);
                headers.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                headers.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                headers.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
                headers.setText("Inv.#");
                headers.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
                headers_row.addView(headers);
                tableLayout.addView(headers_row);

            }
            else {


                data_row.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams());
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv1.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getName()));
                TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv2.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getCredit()));
                TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv3.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getDebt()));
                TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getCredit()));

                data_row.addView(tv1);
                data_row.addView(tv2);
                data_row.addView(tv3);
                data_row.addView(tv4);


            }

            tableLayout.addView(data_row);

        }


        balance_table_SV.addView(tableLayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: this is happening cause you're trying to add a view that has been already added to another view. in this case you're adding the data_row second time in TableLayout. you can solve it by declaring the data_row and header_row (if it's used multiple times) inside the looping statement, so it will be reassigned every time.

Answer (score 0):

This happen cause you are trying to add the same view multiple times in TableLayout. as you are looping through all of your element you have to recreate the data_row again and again for adding it into the table layout.

```
else{
    TableRow data_row = new TableRow(this);

    data_row.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams());
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getName()));
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     tv2.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getCredit()));
    TextView tv3= new TextView(this);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(new
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv3.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getDebt()));
    TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
    tv4.setLayoutParams(new
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bsList.get(i).getCredit()));

    data_row.addView(tv1);
    data_row.addView(tv2);
    data_row.addView(tv3);
    data_row.addView(tv4);
    tableLayout.addView(data_row);
}
```

the above block will solve the problem as it will create the new object of TableRow every time and add it to TableLayout Object

**Explanation:**
while adding the table row second time it will generate the error cause we are trying to add the same table row which being attached to a parent in this case we can consider it as table layout which shows the row.

So Why we require to Create the new TableRow object:
A simple answer will be the same view item can not be at the multiple places.